# Angular cdkDrag boundary parent component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10, angular-cdk

The following code was working as expected.
The `#draggablecontainer` is draggable inside `#mastercontainer` (it doesn't break the boundaries of `.master-container`).

```
<div class="master-container" #mastercontainer> 
  <div class="drag-child" #draggablecontainer cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary=".master-container">
    <div class="drag-header" cdkDragHandle>...</div>
    <div class="drag-body">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But my `#draggablecontainer` will be big, so I decided to make a component. So the code became the following:

Parent component html:

```
<div class="master-container" #mastercontainer> 
<app-child-draggable></app-child-draggable>
</div>
```

Child component html:

```
<div #draggablecontainer class="drag-child" cdkDrag cdkDragBoundary=".master-container">
<div class="drag-header" cdkDragHandle>...</div>
<div class="drag-body">...</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it doesn't recognize the `.master-container`, so I can drag it to out of the screen.

How can I set a `cdkDragBoundary` in a child component with a class declared in the parent component?

Comment: Add an input to your child component and pass `mastercontainer` to it. Use that field as the cdkDragBoundary.

Comment: I've tried that before. In parent component html: [boundary]="mastercontainer", in child component typescript: @Input("boundary") boundary; and in child's HTML: cdkDragBoundary="boundary"

Comment: Did you use square brackets around [cdkDragBoundary] since "boundary" is a variable?